# C# WPF Nested ListView Need SelectedItem Of Parent To Change When Clicking In Child

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

Alright, so this might be a bit hard to explain. I'm putting together a quick scheduling application and for displaying the calendar and the shifts I'm using two nested ListViews (one ListView to display the calendar day and the inner ListView to display the shifts). The problem I'm encountering is that if I click directly into the child ListView that contains the shifts, my parent ListView's SelectedItem doesn't change. I have a contextmenu that will add a new shift when clicked, but since the parent's SelectedItem isn't changing it will add to the wrong day of the month.

Here's some visuals of what I'm talking about:
[Calendar Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjrRK.png)

Here's a general idea of the code I'm talking about:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Schedule.Days}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDay}">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add New Shift" Command="{Binding AddNewShift}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit Shift" Command="{Binding EditShift}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete Shift" Command="{Binding DeleteShift}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Shifts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedShift}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

So when I click directly into the ListView containing Shifts, the SelectedDay of the parent ListView doesn't change, that's the problem I'm trying to address.